# asp.net scheduling / booking system

Tags: asp.net

We want to try fast track developing a booking/scheduling system for a doctor's room.
The faster to market the better!
End of the day, a scheduling product is dirt standard, and i reckon that there must be a ton of good components out there. It just takes time to go through and evaluate.
Ideally we want to do this in asp.net - the system needs to be web based.
Can anyone reccomend something that they have already played with?
Doesn't have to be a freeby. The speedier the dev the better >:)

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about scheduling as in automated process, or scheduling as in booking doctor's time?

Comment: booking patients for different times in different rooms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Application Framework from DevXpress http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/ you can build a simple scheduler with Outlook like interface in a few hours.

Of course, if you are using .NET platform

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about integrating it with Exchange.  It has all that you are looking for probably.

Comment: exchange would be cool, but cant expect clients to outlay for an exchange server

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/), you can write a simple service very easily to handle all you scheduling needs.

Comment: Except for that's not what he's looking for. He wants booking

Comment: Opps, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com), they have a lot of addins/extensions that would probably accomplish what you are looking for, and it is open source.